# how to view graph based on date selection using highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel, highcharts

```html
<form id="form-project" role="form" action="{{action('AltHr\Chatbot\TrackerController@graph')}}" autocomplete="off" method="POST">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  <div class="form-group form-group-default required" >
      <label>Date</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" required>
  </div>
  <button class="btn alt-btn-black btn-xs alt-btn pull-right" type="submit">Select</button>
</form>
```

```html
Route::get('graph','Chatbot\TrackerController@graph');
```

I would like to find out if there is a way that i can show the chart based on selected dates as i have a dates column in my database. If there is, how should i do it? I am using highcharts to generate the pie chart.
Below are the function i did in controller and the javascript to generate the chart in the html tag.

**HTML and JS in blader file**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

    // Build the chart
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false,
                type: 'pie'
            },  
            title: {
                text: 'Pie Chart'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    showInLegend: true
                }
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [
                {
                    name: 'Percentage',
                    colorByPoint: true,
                    data: [{
                        name: 'Questions Asked',
                        y: "{!! $question_asked_sum !!}",
                        sliced: true,
                        selected: true
                    }, {
                        name: 'Low Confidence',
                        y: "{!! $low_confidence_sum !!}"
                    }, {
                        name: 'No Answer',
                        y: "{!! $no_answer_sum !!}"
                    }, {
                        name: 'Missing Intent',
                        y: "{!! $missing_intent_sum !!}"
                    }]
                }
            ]
        });
    });


</script>


<div class="panel-body">
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</div>
```

Function in controller

```
<?php

public function graph() {
    $statistics = DiraStatistics::all();

    $question_asked_sum = $statistics->sum('question_asked');
    $low_confidence_sum = $statistics->sum('low_confidence');
    $no_answer_sum = $statistics->sum('no_answer');
    $missing_intent_sum = $statistics->sum('missing_intent');


    return view('AltHr.Chatbot.graph', compact('question_asked_sum', 'low_confidence_sum', 'no_answer_sum', 'missing_intent_sum'));
}
?>
```

Comment: what are you getting?? I mean your code looks ok to me

Comment: Hi @Mr.Pyramid, currently the code is okay and it views all the data from the database, but now i want to first select a date (maybe a calendar) to view data on that date only.

Comment: you need to pass date from your form or calendar into controller for that

Comment: can you show me your view from where you are requesting `graph()` method?

Comment: @Mr.Pyramid and how do i do that in my current conroller??

Comment: check my answer since I'm not aware about your views I can help you with ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass date in your request I'm assuming you are passing it with `AJAX` here. Since I don't know how you are doing as in your views therefore I'm just adding references for `AJAX` requests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217848/how-to-send-an-ajax-request-to-laravel-5-0-framework)

**NOTE** Make sure about `Get` and `Post` methods.

Then you will get your date in `$request` object which you can use like this:

```
<?php

public function graph(Request $request) {
    $statistics = DiraStatistics::where('dateField',$request->date)->all();

    $question_asked_sum = $statistics->sum('question_asked');
    $low_confidence_sum = $statistics->sum('low_confidence');
    $no_answer_sum = $statistics->sum('no_answer');
    $missing_intent_sum = $statistics->sum('missing_intent');


    return view('AltHr.Chatbot.graph', compact('question_asked_sum', 'low_confidence_sum', 'no_answer_sum', 'missing_intent_sum'));
}
?>
```

I hope it will work for you!

Comment: Hi man, i would really appreciate if you could help me with the AJAX part since i really dont know how to code in AJAX :/

Comment: is it a post route or get??

Comment: I have added a basic structure of ajax with laravel in my answer check it

Comment: it is a get method currently

Comment: ok can you please add the code which you are using for date? I can then add ajax request in my answer?

Comment: you are going wrong here you have get route and your form has post method?

Comment: you want to use post or get method make your final call so that I can answer it accordingly

Comment: @anon please accept the answer if it solves your issue if isn't then let me know and if you have found the answer then please post it to close the question :)